# Long running Bulk Insert locking tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, bulkinsert

I have a stored procedure the does several bulk imports of large amounts of data, upward of 2 million rows each. The process takes around 45 minutes, during which time any associated tables are locked from access. The wait associated with subsequent access to the table is LCK_M_SCH_S.

Is there a way to prevent this wait? All other procedures that access these tables are read only, and the data doesn't have to be perfect so dirty reads would be fine. Or check the lock is there and return an alternative result.

snippet:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY

    truncate table dbo.myTable

    DECLARE @file varchar(500) = 'the dir'

    DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)
    SET @sql = '
            BULK INSERT dbo.myView
            FROM ''' + @file + 'file.txt''
            WITH 
            ( 
                FIELDTERMINATOR =''|'',
                ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
                FIRSTROW = 2,
                CODEPAGE = ''ACP''
            )'
    EXEC(@sql)


END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        --error stuff

    END CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
```

If there is no way around this what other options do I have, would bulk importing into temp tables and updating from there fix this issue?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is when you're doing to bulk operation. Do this SP's always need to be able to access the table? Do you have times where you could schedule the bulk operation to perform during a less busy time? I.e. outside of business hours.

Comment: There is no time of the day this wouldn't be a problem, unfortunately.

Comment: At this point I think you need to try inserting into a #temp

Comment: Use SSIS to import the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option might be to have 2 copies of your data and use a `VIEW`. The view points to the one copy of your table, and you do your bulk operation on the other. Once the bulk operation is done, then you update the definition of the view to look at the table that has had the bulk operation completed.

You then update the original table or that one is updated the next time the bulk operation happens and you swap the object in the view each time. This isn't an ideal solution though, however, you can't really avoid table locks like you want; and I never suggest with `NOLOCK` query hint.

I wouldn't be surprised if this answer gets a couple of down votes, as it's not great, but it does serve the purpose.

---

On a different note I would change `FROM ''' + @file + 'file.txt''` to `FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@file + 'file.txt','''')`. I don't know where the value of `@file` is coming from, however, SQL injection is not your friend.

Comment: Would it be possible to do a similar thing using partition switching? That might have smaller chance of breaking things than renaming objects.

Comment: I've little experience with partitions @JamesZ, so unsure. I'm sure someone who knows how they work will be able to answer that though. :)

Comment: I like the view idea, I'll look into whether this is feasible. I have only read "nolock is bad", but never seen any examples of it's use, I'm guess it wouldn't bypass a schema lock? Or would you use this on the bulk insert and not the subsequent request to the tables that are locked? The filename is internal, but I like the suggestion, you are correct.

Comment: @JamesZ I'll have a look into partition switching too, thanks.

Comment: Partition switching works best when performing incremental updates against giant tables. But basically the way it works is exactly what Larnu is describing so you could use for a huge table. When you "switch" partitions it just changes the pointer in the background. The main negative you might hit is that you can't partition a table after creation, but you could make a new one and use some sp_rename to easily transition.

Comment: @JamesZ you should make a legit answer for partition switching, it is the better mechanic in this case.